# Adjusting list items side by side without scrolling

Tags: html, css

i'm having list items which are dynamically populated in single column. but, i'm looking to display the list items in side by side columns if it crosses certain height something like below:

1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d
5. e
6. f
7. g
8. h

to ==>

1. a   5. e
2. b   6. f
3. c   7. g
4. d   8. h

Comment: Can you share some code of what you have tried?

Comment: Hi, questions asking us to write code for your requirements are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they are not about solving a specific problem with code, but rather are asking the community to do your work for you. Instead, make an attempt at writing code and if you encounter a problem, narrow the question to that specific problem and show what has been done so far to try solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's what you want:

```
<ol>
  <li>Lorem.</li>
  <li>Iure.</li>
  <li>Eos.</li>
  <li>Dolore?</li>
  <li>Voluptatibus!</li>
  <li>Voluptates.</li>
  <li>Mollitia.</li>
  <li>Veniam?</li>
</ol>
```

```
ol {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 10ch;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: hi @ercüment thanks for responding, the content is overflowing in x-axis, is it because of max-height and width restrictions?

Comment: Yes. You can give the width as you want.